# exception com.apple.coreaudio.avfaudio reason: error -50

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, core-audio, avaudiosession

I have this message when i try to play an audio with a different pitch:
[image]

And i googled for that error with no succeed. If i set breakpoints it stops here:
[image]

I test printing all objects to see is anything is nit but i didnt found anything. The most misterious thing is that only happens in my iphone6+, in other phones i tested this out doesnt break. Then searched the project where i looked into to add this sound effects which is this:
https://github.com/atikur/Pitch-Perfect
And if you run it it works, until you change...

```
AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord, error: &error)
```

To:

```
AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, error: &error)
```

And then boom (ONLY IN REAL DEVICE ATTACHED TO XCODE, it works in the simulator):

2015-03-21 11:56:13.311 Pitch Perfect[1237:607678] 11:56:13.311 ERROR:     [0x10320c000] AVAudioFile.mm:496: -[AVAudioFile readIntoBuffer:frameCount:error:]: error -50
2015-03-21 11:56:13.313 Pitch Perfect[1237:607678] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'com.apple.coreaudio.avfaudio', reason: 'error -50'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x18687a530 0x1978040e4 0x18687a3f0 0x1851ea6c0 0x185232d38 0x1852130f8 0x185212ccc 0x100584fd4 0x100584f94 0x10058fdb8 0x1005882c4 0x1005925d4 0x100592208 0x198037dc8 0x198037d24 0x198034ef8)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

And the really really weird thing is this screenshot, for some reason after printing audioEngine, audioEngine.outputNode gets nil?
[image: weird bug]

Comment: I'm getting the same error. In the terminal if you type `macerror -50` it responds: `Mac OS error -50 (paramErr): error in user parameter list`. I haven't gotten any further yet.

Comment: this audio programming in iOS sucks!

Comment: I made the sound class a singleton and it fixed my crashes

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error... I had created a "sound.swift" class that my view controller would instantiate... I decided to simplify everything and focus on making the sound work. So I have put the following code in the view controller and it works:

//fetch recorded file

```
var pitchPlayer = AVAudioPlayerNode()
var timePitch = AVAudioUnitTimePitch()
let dirPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory,.UserDomainMask,true)[0] as! String

var pathArray = [dirPath, String("son.wav")]

filePath = NSURL.fileURLWithPathComponents(pathArray)

audioFile = AVAudioFile(forReading: filePath.filePathURL, error: nil)

audioEngine = AVAudioEngine()

audioEngine.attachNode(pitchPlayer)
audioEngine.attachNode(timePitch)


//Create a session
var session=AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
session.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord,error:nil)

//output audio
session.overrideOutputAudioPort(AVAudioSessionPortOverride.Speaker, error: nil)

audioEngine.connect(pitchPlayer, to: timePitch, format: audioFile.processingFormat)
audioEngine.connect(timePitch, to: audioEngine.outputNode, format: audioFile.processingFormat)

pitchPlayer.scheduleFile(audioFile, atTime: nil, completionHandler: nil)
audioEngine.startAndReturnError(&audioError)

pitchPlayer.play()
```